# Why I'm getting this socket error at the time of opening Unity? And how can I resolve it?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

**Socket: unable to join multicast group, error: An invalid argument was supplied.
(10022)**

**Unable to join player connection multicast group.**

**Unable to join player connection alternative multicast group.**
[image]

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/socket-unable-to-join-multicast-group.164413/

Comment: I already followed those but my errors not get resolved

Comment: I have the same problem, could you solve it?

Comment: Try updating or reentering your license key. It worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the reason for this error is with License Key.
Try updating it at

**Unity Hub -> Settings -> License Management -> Check for Updates**

or else
you can re-enter your serial key by clicking on **Activate a New License**

This may help you, somebody.
But there may be other reasons like with Version Control System like Git.

I found a solution by the Customer QA Team of Unity.

Comment: doesn't work for me, having same issue everytime I open the project. (Unity 2021.3.31f1)